# Calcular a expressão matemática usando vetor em c++

Tags: array, c++, matemática

Oi, meu professor passou o seguinte exercício: Elabore um algoritmo que dado três vetores reais de 5 posições, leia estes vetores, calcule a expressão ((vetor1 * vetor3) / vetor2 ), utilizando os valores da mesma posição, armazenando em um quarto vetor, também de números reais de 5 posições. No final, imprima os números do quarto vetor.

Eu tentei de várias formas e com diversos valores porém o código compila porém da o erro:

nan

nan

nan

0

0

Eis o algoritmo:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

int i;
float v1[5], v2[5], v3[5], v4[5]; 
 
cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 1: \n"; 
for (i=1;i<=5;i++) 
{ 
 cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
 cin >> v1[i]; 
} 
 
cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 2: \n"; 
for (i=1;i<=5;i++) 
{ 
 cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
 cin >> v1[i]; 
} 

cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 3: \n"; 
for (i=1;i<=5;i++) 
{ 
 cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
 cin >> v1[i]; 
} 

for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    v4[i]=((v1[i]*v3[i])/v2[i]);
}

cout << "RESULTADOS DO VETOR 4: \n";

for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    cout << v4[i] << "\n";
}

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não parei pra analisar todo o código, mas de cara já vi uma coisa que está errado: arrays são indexados em zero, ou seja, o primeiro elemento está na posição zero, o segundo na posição 1, e assim por diante. Sendo assim, os loops deveriam ser `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: Atá, tinha esquecido kkkkk. Vou testar aqui, muito obrigado.

Comment: É necessário ter uma resposta, que você possa então "aceitar". Se você mesmo encontrou a solução você pode responder e aceitar sua própria resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo, eu tenho costume de usar o scanf e printf pra salvar os dados e mostra-los na tela. então alterei uma parte do seu código pra ficar dessa forma: funcionando perfeitamente, espero tê-lo ajudado

```
                #include <iostream>
            #include <locale.h>
            
            using namespace std;
            int main()
            {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
            
            int i;
            float v1[5], v2[5], v3[5], v4[5]; 
             
            cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 1: \n"; 
            for (i=0;i<5;i++) 
            { 
            // cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
            // cin >> v1[i]; 
            printf("Entre com o valor %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%f",&v1[i]);
            
            } 
             
            cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 2: \n"; 
            for (i=0;i<5;i++) 
            { 
            // cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
            // cin >> v1[i]; 
            printf("Entre com o valor %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%f",&v2[i]);
            
            } 
            
            cout << "VALORES DO VETOR 3: \n"; 
            for (i=0;i<5;i++) 
            { 
            // cout << "Entre com o valor " << i << ":\n"; 
            // cin >> v1[i]; 
            printf("Entre com o valor %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%f",&v3[i]);
            
            } 
            
            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
            
                v4[i]=((v1[i]*v3[i])/v2[i]);
            }
            
            cout << "RESULTADOS DO VETOR 4: \n";
            
            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                printf("%f\n",v4[i]);
            }
            
            system ("PAUSE");
            return 0;
            }
```